# Term for "Phrase that Ends List"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

In an episode of Fawlty Towers, Basil Fawlty uses the phrase ["And Bob's your uncle"](http://goo.gl/03bXhR). Unfamiliar with it, I looked the phrase up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle), which described it this way:

> Typically, someone says ["*And Bob's your uncle*"] to conclude a set of simple instructions, similar to the French expression "et voilà!" or the American slang expressions "...and that's that," or "...and there you go!"

Thinking about it more, I can see a variety of phrases going into this slot. Consider the example sentence,

> Take the bread out of the bag, put the bread in the toaster, push the button down, and -- *PHRASE* -- you've got toast!

In the place of *PHRASE* I have heard some of the following:

- Interrogatives

  - *What do you get/have?*
  - *Whaddaya know?*
  - *Isn't that something?*
- Sayings

  - *Drumroll, please*
  - *Badda-bing, badda-boom*
  - *Surprise, surprise*
- Interjections

  - *(Abracadabra) alakazam!*
  - *Ta-da!*
  - *Presto!*

A word I learned recently is [*phatic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression):

> a **phatic expression** /ˈfætɨk/ is one whose only function is to perform a social task, as opposed to conveying information

*Phatic* nearly seems to fit, except:

1. The *PHRASE*, though less informative than its neighbors, may have another function: to indicate the list is ending
2. Even though some definitions allow for [building emotional rapport](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phatic) (*"of, relating to, or being speech used for social or emotive purposes rather than for communicating information"*), which the examples do with suspense or anticipation, the examples I find tend to be about [pleasantries](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/phaticterm.htm) such as talking about the weather

The examples need not interrupt the list, as shown in the Fawlty excerpt:

> [If] it turns out you don't like your room, then we could always move you in here, but I don't think it's worth doing until you've definitely decided that you don't like that one as much as this one, and then we can sort of sit down round a table, discuss it, chew it over and ... and then it will be a piece of cake. Bob's your uncle...."

Most generally, I'm looking for a term with the definition "a phrase (usually with the audience's emotional state in mind) concluding sequential statements." This definition also covers phrases like ["And then I found five dollars"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=and%20then%20I%20found%20five%20dollars) (used when the speaker fears they have bored their audience).

Is there a term to describe this pattern?

Comment: Bingo! Fits well too. *"Place slice of bread in toaster and bingo! You now have toast."*

Comment: These things are (when clauses) traditionally known as 'comment clauses' (although there is the semantic content here of 'mission accomplished'). I suppose they are _concluding comment clauses_.

Comment: Phatic expressions can be considered a subset of pragmatic markers (strings having or approaching non-propositionality, appended to sentences). In general, these may be text-organisational (next, ...), message-orientated (probably, ...; speaking as an economist, ...) or addressee-orientated (now look, ...; please ...; what do you get?). This third set is the same set as (or an overlapping set with) 'phatic expressions'. Some (including some of your examples) fulfil more than one role.

Comment: How about "punchline" or "tailpiece"

Comment: In the UK at least, "Bob's your uncle" is often met with the rejoinder, "And Fanny's your aunt". See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20346/bobs-your-uncle-no-hes-not. My personal use is to terminate a list of things with "Bag of Nuts. String of beads and a football match."

Comment: Not necessarily list-enders, these can occur anywhere. The title is not what the body talks about (a whole range of things, not one). I am quite sure, it's not pragmatic to look for **one** name (or hypernym) for those. No offense, look again. ExSum: Overambitious :)

Comment: My observation is on neither primary nor sole but potential use. Many terms *can be* (but don't have to be) used this way, which makes me wonder if there is a term for this phenomenon. But I agree that such a term (if one exists) seems good for little more than trivia.

Comment: When the phrase is used to convey to the listener that the list of instructions is being ended, it is being used as a vocalized delimiter.

Comment: Also: Voila! (indicating the desired result is visible) or Kerching! (indicating success has been obtained).

Comment: A **valediction** is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **rhetorical** [**flourish**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flourish) or simply **flourish** for this usage.

A flourish (n) is:

> an act or instance of brandishing or waving
> a :  a florid bit of speech or writing *rhetorical flourishes*
> b :  an ornamental stroke in writing or printing
> c :  a decorative or finishing detail *a house with clever little flourishes*

I think that it fits the bill quite well for ending a list with a little zinger like *And, Bob's your uncle!*

Comment: Before @FumbleFingers yells at me (again) for reiterating my dictionary link ... It was too jumbled and I wanted to highlight the features. ;-)