# Where did "Bob" come from?

Tags: etymology

Examples:

1. Yes Siree Bob
2. Bob's your uncle

Who is bob and where did he/she come from?

Comment: The earliest attestation to "Bob's your uncle" that I could find online is from a song title from 1931. https://books.google.com/books?id=ZS5jAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1492&dq=%22bob%27s+your+uncle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIgIX0qd_gAhUSd98KHembBx4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22bob's%20your%20uncle%22&f=false

Comment: Related: [“Bob's your uncle” … no he's not!](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20346/216106)

Comment: I get plenty of hits when I google these phrases + etymology. Does that online search not give you what you want to know? I close-voted as no research presented in the question.

Comment: @k1eran:  Which one of those hits actually presents evidence for its theory?

Comment: @TRomano I kind of think the onus is on Justin to do that legwork ?

Comment: @k1eran: Your close-vote was premature unless you had visited those hits and found at least one that was authoritative.

Comment: The "Bob" in examples 1 and 2 come from two different places. For example 2, the question is a duplicate; for example 1, the question is far from a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etymology of "Bob"  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Bob#etymonline_v_52930)

Bob

> a familiar shortening and alteration of the masc. proper name Robert.
>   British slang phrase **Bob's your uncle** "everything's all right" is
>   attested by 1937. It seems to echo the old use noted in the 1725
>   "Canting Dictionary," which reports "Bob ... signifies Safety, ... as,
>   It's all Bob, i. e. All is safe, the Bet is secured."

Answer (score 1):

a quick Google Shows this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle

> The origins are uncertain, but a common theory is that the expression arose after Conservative Prime Minister Robert "Bob" Cecil appointed his nephew Arthur Balfour as Chief Secretary for Ireland in 1887, an act which was apparently both surprising and unpopular. Whatever other qualifications Balfour might have had, "Bob's your uncle" was seen as the conclusive one.

Comment: This youtube video agrees. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsCWbLSHZG0   I think Bob is easy, versatile, and familiar as a name form. Origins of each and every "Bob" expression will be different. It's sort of like a person-less name that everyone knows.

Comment: Without attestations such theories are mere speculation. Has anyone found attestations from the 19th century?